# For iOS 12 or higher display notification (sent via APNS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, remote-notifications

Register for remote notifications
For iOS 12 or higher display notification (sent via APNS)
I just need to add the below code, right?

```
let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

No need if-else like the example for iOS 10:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/365e43642f2cc570df004cb16e098a76cde1e5b1/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L40-L55

Answer (score 0):

That’s right. I've tried this code and it works well.

For devices running iOS 10 and above, you must assign the **UNUserNotificationCenter**'s **delegate** property and **FIRMessaging**'s delegate property. For example, in an iOS app, assign it in the **applicationWillFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** or **applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** method of the app delegate.